# How to stub parameters from a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

For my tests I need a controller where I can set my own parameters. With parameters I mean the one you get when invoking `controller.params`

```
{"action"=>"show",
 "controller"=>"merchants",
 "wine_id"=>"1",
 "id"=>"346343"}
```

The problem is, I don't know what the proper way for stubbing is here. There are three occurrences:

- `controller.request.env['action_dispatch.request.path_parameters']`
- `controller.params`
- `controller.url_options[:_recall]`

In all three the same information is stored, but what's the interfaced way to set these values?

Comment: Do you mean specifically in your test suite?

Comment: Are you saying that you access the parameters via all three methods?

Comment: @Donovan Yes @PeterAlfvin No. It seems in the end it all comes down to `controller.request.env['action_dispatch.request.path_parameters']` looking at the source code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Usual way of accessing params is by `controller.params`. So i would advise you to stub params

```
controller.stub(:params).and_return({:param1 => "value", :param2 => "value"})
```

Comment: Yeah, from the one working in the controller definitely, but Rails itself goes over controller.request.path_parameters when working with the parameters internally. The stub method is very handy, didn't know that one.

Comment: I'm putting this in my RSpec test inside an example, but I'm getting a `LocalJumpError: no block given
from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-rails-3.5.2/lib/rspec/rails/example/controller_example_group.rb:77:in `class_exec'`

Comment: @usha would you know how to stub params from request specs?